# Template issues in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, compiler-errors, linker

The issue I'm having here is `class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl operator<<(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class Sadrzaj const &)`. I have searched far and wide on the Internet for a solution but could not find it. The issue occurs when I try to include `Data.h` in the main source file, the same happens with `Content.h`. Down below are the two header files for reference. Any help whatsoever is greatly appreciated. :-)

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class Content
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &str, const Content&);
public:
    virtual void print(std::ostream&) const = 0;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &str, const Content& temp)
{
    temp.print(str);
    return str;
}

#pragma once
#include "Content.h"

template <class T>
class Data: public Content
{
public:
    Data(const T&);
    void print(std::ostream&) const override;
private:
    T data;
};

template <class T>
Data<T>::Data(const T& data) : data(data) {}

template <class T>
void Data<T>::print(std::ostream& str) const { str << data; }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message from the compiler? Add the **exact** text of the error message.

Comment: What *exact* error do you get? Also, try to program in English, because that's what everyone does and therefore it'll be easier to ask for, give, and receive help from and to anyone.

Comment: `friend std::ostream& Sadrzaj::operator<<` doesn't make sense. perhaps remove the `Sadrzaj::` part

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the problem was that the << operator was defined in the "Content.h" header file. Simply by creating a new source file "Content.cpp" and defining it there, the problem was solved. If anyone knows why this solved the error, I would appreciate it very much if they would explain it to me, so that I don't make the same mistake again. :-)